# Induced matchings in a bipartite graph with every matching having the same number of edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Suppose $n,k$ are positive integers such that $k\mid n$.

Consider a bipartite graph $H=(A,B,E)$ such that $|A|=|B|=n$ and the edge set $E$ consists of the union of $m(H)$ induced matchings with every matching having $k$ edges.

Let $g(n,k)$ be the maximum of $m(H)$ where $H$ runs over all such graphs. Then it is easy to see that $(\frac{n}{k})^2\leq g(n,k)\leq \frac{n(n+1-k)}{k}$.

Is there any better upper bound of $g(n,k)$?

Comment: I guess you mean "Consider ***a*** bipartite graph H...". Can you please check if my edits agree with what you mean?

Comment: In the case when $k$ is linear in $n$, some sharp bounds are given by Fox, Huang and Sudakov: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/linear-induced-matchings.pdf

Comment: Wolfgang: Yes, your edits agree with what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: Shagnik: Thank you very much for your help!